# OAuth Consent Screen doesn't includes app’s Client ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

Trying to submit my app to google for verification and they require a video showing the OAuth consent screen showing the client ID. However instead of the client ID it shows
"accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?access_type=offline&login_hint="

In the credentials tab it shows the OAuth 2.0 Client ID was automatically created for the app and I also tried creating a new one, is there a step or setting I missed?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the actual consent screen you're getting (free of sensitive information)? Also, do you have access to [Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?authuser=0)?

Comment: @lamblichus, added screenshot. Thanks I'll look into the workspace support.

Comment: I do not have a admin account so I can't access workspace support.

Comment: `However instead of the client ID it shows "accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?access_type=offline&login_hint="`: I don't see that in your screenshot. Could you please provide that? Also, can't you contact the verification team in order to clarify this?